# "R Fatal error cannot open file RSOCKnode.R" when attempting to use snowfall

Tags: r

I'm running R 3.2.3 on RHEL 6.5.7 and attempting to set up a R cluster using the snowfall package.

From the documentation I'm issuing the command,

```
R --no-save ---no-restore --args --parallel --type=SOCK --hosts=worker0.example.com:16,worker1.example.com:16
```

R starts up with

> WARNING: unknown option '---no-restore'

Again, according to the documentation I load the snowfall library

```
library(snowfall)
```

and then

```
sfInit()
```

But instead of seeing

> snowfall 1.70 initialized: parallel execution on 32 CPUs.

What I get is

> Fatal error: cannot open file '/home/myself/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/snow/RSOCKnode.R': No such file or directory

And R is hung until I hit Control-C.  The file exists in the path specified and seems to have the correct ownership and permissions (644 and owned by myself).  I invoke R as myself so I'm stumped as to why I'm getting this error.

==========================================

Update

snowfall works if I try to run it on only a single workstation

```
library(snowfall)
Loading required package: snow
> sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=4, type="SOCK")
R Version:  R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

snowfall 1.84-6.1 initialized (using snow 0.4-1): parallel execution on 4 CPUs.
```

And this is running R as myself but invoking it without the command line arguments that the snowfall package documentation shows as example commands.

Comment: Maybe try running R with admin privileges?

Comment: Do you want to use `--no-restore` instead if `---no-restore`?

Comment: --no-restore is part of snowfall's documentation's example command to set up the cluster.  So that's why I included it.  Now the documentation hasn't been updated since 2014 and so that command line argument might be out of date.

Comment: Since the file R is claiming doesn't exist is owned by myself and had 644 permissions I don't see what difference running R as admin would make.  And the snowfall package documentation doesn't say that snow needs to be run as admin either. but I'll give it a try just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the documentation is way out of date that is in the package vignette.  The real argument is

```
sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=16, type="SOCK", socketHosts=c("worker0.example.com","worker1.example.com"))
```

At least when invoked from within R.